# How do I group my data by specific date ranges, like hour, day, month?

Tags: looker-studio

My data contains two timestamps `start` and `end`. How do I group it so that I can show all the data points where the diff of end-start is less than a month, less than a week, day etc.?

Example data:

| start | end | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-15 23:00:00 UTC | 2022-06-24 22:00:00 UTC | 120 |
| 2021-12-17 23:00:00 UTC | 2022-01-16 23:00:00 UTC | 93 |
| 2021-12-17 23:00:00 UTC | 2022-01-16 23:00:00 UTC | 99 |

I want to annotate the data with a new field called `duration` with values like `hour`, `day`, `week`, `month`

Answer (score 0):

When editing the data source, it's possible to add new 'calculated fields'.
I used DATETIME_DIFF to annotate the duration like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN DATETIME_DIFF(end, start, HOUR) <= 1 THEN "Hour"
    WHEN DATETIME_DIFF(end, start, DAY) <= 1 THEN "Day"
    WHEN DATETIME_DIFF(end, start, DAY) <= 7 THEN "Week"
    ELSE "Month"
END
```